# Hibernate same object with different values

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one class with specific columns, say

```
Class A
{
    private String A;
    private String B;
    private String C;

    // Getter Setter of respectives
}
```

Now what happened I have same value of column **A** and column **B** only column **C**'s value change. So I do something like below

```
A a = new A();
a.setA(..);
a.setB(..);

for(i=0;i<length;i++){
     a.setC(..);

     getHibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(a);

     // or something like this
     // A a1 = new A();
     // a1 = a;
     // a1. setC(..);
     // getHibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(a1);

}
```

My issue is it does not store length number of records, it only updates that single record.

I know the reason that hibernate access it as persistent object and even if I change value and again save it will update existing record and it can be resolve by taking **new object every time and setting it all values**. But I don't want it, is there any way to tell hibernate to save that record instead of updating?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't described actual entity details. If you want to save entity with the same values, set the identifier property as `null`.

From Documentation -

**saveOrUpdate()**

- if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing
- if another object associated with the session has the same
  identifier, throw an exception
- if the object has no identifier property, save() it
- if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly
  instantiated object, save() it
- if the object is versioned by a  or , and the
  version property value is the same value assigned to a newly
  instantiated object, save() it
- otherwise update() the object

**saveOrUpdateAll()**

- Save or update all given persistent instances, according to its id (matching the configured "unsaved-value"?). Associates the instances with the current Hibernate Session.

[*If it works, can try this for your other  [query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17568898/366964)*]

---

**Edit :** It's mine oversight, I haven't checked your code carefully.
You have defined object `A` outside for loop, therefore the same object was being updated in each iteration. Try the below code, might help.

```
for(i=0;i<length;i++){
A a = new A();  //-- Create new object for each iteration
a.setA(..);
a.setB(..);
a.setC(..);

getHibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(a);
}
```

Comment: I had tried by setting identifier value with null, but it does not work.

Comment: That will work, but I dont want to set setA() and setB() again that's my concern.

Comment: @commit For that, you can explicitly define method in entity to return a new object having default values or appropriate constructor or can `clone()` & then can set only required field to be altered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.Try  `save(a)`  instead of  `saveOrUpdate(a)`

```
getHibernateTemplate.save(a);  //each time a new object saves.
```

Comment: Thanks, I have upvoted for your solution but this will not work for me, this is only consept of my code because whole code I can't explain here however in my code I am using method for saving whole collection by saveOrUpdateAll() and hibernateTemplate class has not saveAll() method, In that case what should I do? I have thought about this before and I have asked related this question here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568898/hibernatetemplate-saveorupdateall.