# HibernateTemplate SaveOrUpdateAll

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

HibernateTemplate class has following method

```
getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll(Collection entities)
```

But why it has not only `saveAll()` method? like this

```
getHibernateTemplate().saveAll(Collection entities)
```

what happened if I only want to save collection not to update it?

Answer (score 0):

saveOrUpdateAll(Collection entities) itself will serve the purpose of saveAll(Collection entities) also.. this could be the reason

Comment: Obviously, but what happened if I want to force hibernate to save my collection not to update it, in that case I need saveAll() method like save().